# Is this legal use of a for loop?

Tags: c++

For instance:

```
 vector<int> something;
 //imagine i add some elements to the vector here

 int* pointy;
 for (int i = 0; i < something.size(); pointy = &something[i++]) {
      //do some work with pointy
 }
```

it seems to work and saves me a line but is there any danger of weird bugs popping up down the line because of this?

Comment: It's safe enough, but you're getting into obfuscated code territory. This won't produce code which is any faster, so you're better off making everything explicit. If you really want the loop to work like this, you could use iterators (you won't know the loop index but you'll get a pointer to each element).

Comment: Why don'- you use the iterators provided by `std::vector` ??

Comment: No. It is fine. The third argument expects a valid expression. And it gets it.

Comment: The above code snippit leaves pointy uninitialized on the first iteration.

Comment: cant use iterators in this case because in the actual loop i need the i as well

Comment: Well, you can get the offset of a random-access iterator by `iterator - something.begin()`, but I see that you want to set both the offset and the value/pointer outside of the `{...}`, which is possible but produces hard to read code.

Comment: This is asking for trouble just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may not be legal, because `pointy` is unassigned on the first iteration. If the loop does not dereference `pointy` during the initial iteration, it may be OK, but it is not possible to tell without seeing the body of the loop.

Since you are using `std::vector`, using iterators would save you another line, because you wouldn't need to declare `pointy`. You would be able to determine the offset without `i` by subtracting `something.begin()` from the current iterator:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator iter = something.begin() ; iter != something.end() ; ++iter) {
    cout << "Item at index " << (iter - something.begin()) << " is " << *iter << endl;
}
```

Comment: I actually hadn't noticed that. Yay obfuscation!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is dangerous, [as dasblinkenlight pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16882532/1932150). But there's a simpler way to eliminate this kind of problems.

**Write your code for simplicity and readability first**. Compressing your loop into the smallest possible number of lines won't add anything in terms of performance, and even if it did, you shouldn't care as long as your profiler doesn't tell you that your loop is a bottleneck.

On the other hand, it will make your code harder to read and, possibly, more prone to bugs (as you've probably noticed).

In C++11, consider using a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (int& p : something)
{
   // ...
}
```

In C++03, consider using [`std::for_each()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), or a classical loop based on iterators:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = something.begin(); i != something.end(); ++i)
{
    // use *i to refer to the current pointy
    // use (i - something.begin()) to get its index
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The range-based for loop is definitely the way to go in C++11. Nice that you also mentioned the algorithm `std::for_each` for C++03, but without lambdas it really produces obfuscated code in my opinion, unless a reusable functor can be used.

Comment: @leemes: True, `std::for_each` without lambdas is a painful thing. On the other hand, the first 8 characters are clear about the purpose of the loop, while in the case of a manual loop you would actually have to go and look inside the loop to make sure `i` is not being manipulated, and that what it does is to iterate over each element. But yes, I agree the functor-based approach is annoying. I'd probably go more often for the manual loop than not in C++03.

Comment: I totally agree with the "fixed" semantics when using a std algorithm, which is one of their powerful strengths.

Answer (score 1):

It is very dangerous, because `i` is not `unsigned`. It can blow up in some rare cases. :)

Comment: In what way can it blow up?

Comment: If `something.size() > INT_MAX` (it is possible) it will be infinite loop. If a PC stays in infinite loop for a long time, it can blow up.

Comment: If `something.size() > INT_MAX`, you would, strictly speaking, get undefined behaviour. But the solution to this is to use `std::vector<int>::size_type` (which is not necessarily the same as `unsigned`). If you want to be really strict.

Comment: The standard allows for undefined behaviour to blow up the computer and/or internet.

Answer (score 0):

Is this safe really depends on what you are after.
pointy is going to be a pointer to an element in the vector.
This means that if you change the value of pointy, or what it points to be more specific, you are actually changing the content of the vector for that specific element.

Comment: So what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I like to handle std::vector like this for larger Objects:

```
std::vector<int*> mynumbers;
//add elements here like this:
int somenumber = 5;
mynumbers.push_back(&somenumber);

for(int i=0;i<elemnts.size();i++)
{
    cout << "Element Nr. " << i << ": " << *elements.at(i) << endl;
    //modify like this:
    *elements.at(i) = 0;
}
```

The pointer instead of the variable itself is because std::vector handles pointers faster than large objects itself, but for int, this doesn't really make much difference so you can also do it like this:

```
std::vector<int> mynumbers;
mynumbers.push_back(5);

int* pointy
for(int i=0;i<elemnts.size();i++)
{
    pointy = &elements.at(i);
}
```

Works great for me!

Comment: What is the motivation for switching from `vector<int>` to `vector<int*>`?

Comment: For int, it doesn't really make much sense, but when you try to manage an array of larger objects holding a lot of data, std::vector will handle some pointers quite faster than the objects itself. I'll add this to my answer...

Comment: But you realize there can be many problems with pushing the addresses of local variables to the vector, right? Typically you will end up allocating the objects dynamically, and that's a huge overhead. Anyway how is this related to the question? The question is about the complex for-statement.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to explain, that you don't need the iterators for this and jogojapan asked, why I used pointers and I tried to explain that too. And I also said, that the pointer stuff doesn't make much sense for ints, but i wanted to give the option too.

Comment: But the code in the question doesn't even use iterators. It uses the same technique as your for-loop (a counter instead of iterators). But it contains this complex statement: `pointy = &something[i++]` inside the for-statement, and the question is whether this is OK. Your suggestion seems to be to use pointers and `at` instead of `[]`, but how does that answer the question. Sorry to annoy you, but I really think answers should be related to the question.

Comment: Yep, I just figured, that a little hint could be useful, as the direct answer to the question was already given. And also I wanted to give and alternativ to the `pointy = &something[i++]` thing. Because when he wants to get a pointer, he needs to do that in the mainloop itself! Ok, maybe it was not the best answer, I apologize for that.